# Proof that a set $E_n$ is not absorbing

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $E_n = \{f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{K} \text{ measureable} \,|\, \int_{[0,1]} \lvert f \rvert ^3dm < n\}\subset L^2([0,1],m)$. I need to determine whether $E_n$ is absobing.

My Proof: It is known result that $L^3([0,1],m)\subsetneq L^2([0,1],m)$. So take an $f\in L^2([0,1],m)\setminus L^3([0,1],m)$. But then 
$$
\int_{[0,1]} \lvert f \rvert^3 dm = \infty
$$
and this means that for no real $r$ for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{K}$ such that $\lvert \alpha\rvert\geq r$ implies that
$\alpha f\in E_n$ for any $n$.

Comment: Okay. It would be better, however, to give an explicit example of an $f \in L^2\setminus L^3$.

Comment: Thanks, I included $f(x)=1_{(0,1]}x^{-1/3}$ as an example.